# Can I repair Lubuntu 14.04 after trying Mate live usb key?

Tags: filesystem, live-usb, mate

Lubuntu 14.04 64 is the only OS on my laptop (HP, UEFI boot). I wanted to have a look at Mate 16.04, so I downloaded the 64 bit ISO file and made a USB live key using Startup Disk Creator with persistence. I tried the live USB and never pressed the button for installing Mate on my HDD. I just found out that persistence did not work. Then I left and was away for one month.
On my return (today) I started Lubuntu 14.04 and Software Update warned:

CD/DVD 'Ubuntu-MATE 16.04.1 LTS *Xenial Xerus* - Release amd64 (20160719)' is required

Please insert the above CD/DVD into the drive '/media/cdrom/' to install software packages from it.

The weird thing is, I never had that CD. I've tried to plug in my usb key with the live version of Mate but this isn't what Software Update requires.
I checked Synaptic Package Manager: the list of the repositories now includes Xenial (main, restricted and universe) from Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 LTS Xenial Xerus. The following packages turn out to have been installed on my system from Xenial Mate main:

dkms
fakeroot
gcc
grub-efi-amd64
grub-efi-amd64-bin
grub-efi-amd64-signed
libatomic1
libc-dev-bin
libc6-dev
libfakeroot
libitm1
libtsan0
linux-libc-dev
manpages-dev

I feel fairly sure that my system is broken. This is the PC I daily use for working, I have tuned it up to meet my needs. I simply cannot afford reinstalling everything now because I don't have time.
I'd be VERY grateful if anyone could suggest a way for recovering my system.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 16.04 solved my problem.

I tried more conservative ways first: I disabled the new repositories and especially the Mate DVD and I launched a new software update. But the updater always detected a partly upgraded system and so the architecture of my system was both Lubuntu-Trusty and Mate-Xenial.
The upgrade went straight and smooth: all the packages I've tried work out of the box, but it especially removed the Mate Xenial repositories and software and replaced them with Lubuntu Xenial ones. The only surviving (but unchecked) Mate repository was the DVD: I erased it for good from Software & Updates.

Therefore the answer to the question is YES, you can *repair* Lubuntu, but I don't know if it could be *restored*.